# MatrixRate Table Rate Shipping Webshop

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am using this extension for shipping rate "https://webshopapps.com/row/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html".

When i am adding one 1 product with 3kg weight, then on checkout page shipping method coming as per the csv imported for 3kg weight.

Now i am adding another product with same 3kg weight. So now total is 6kg weight. But when i am adding more then 1 product in cart than my define csv shipping methods are not coming on checkout page.

What i am doing wrong, can anyone please help me out with this?

[image]

[image]

https://prnt.sc/qdgpvz

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add your Shipping configuration and CSV in question.

Comment: I have added my configuration, csv screen shot and the checkout page link error.

Comment: I have added two product in cart with total weight of 7kg.